# productivity flaws

Tags: discussion

can someone point out why i was downvoted, i've reviewed the rules, i moderate on other sites and i work in these fields... i feel as though someone has gone through every single post and downvoted them well thats at least what it looks like in the rep bar for me on this visit... this spans many different subs here and has just happened since my last log on a few days ago... no reasons no input or answers as to what may be incorrect. ive obviously angered someone here.

this seems unproductive and more like borderline harassment or at least passive aggressive behavior... maybe thats just the norm here... just noticing someone recently has gone through all of my posts... any advice would be greatly appreciated i hope the mods have management or at least customer service skills here this place is starting to leave a bad taste
and

i will be probably not be coming back after doing a quick search into the behavior of this community it seems this place may have thrived years ago but it may have turned into a haunt that caters to the few rather than the many. reminds me of yotatech after 2006

please dont edit this instead show it to someone who might care to help this cool place see a productivity flaw in its formula or at least stop however is trolling me everywhere i go thanks.

Comment: I've moved this here because questions concerning how the site works and issues such as this belongs on Meta. I will look at what you are asking here and respond when I get home.

Comment: Paulster2 has covered all the points, but all moderators are awake and they look for serial downvoting - it was happening to me a while back, the first I knew was the mod contacting me saying we’ve corrected stuff... I had not even noticed :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll have to apologize if you are feeling picked on, but I can pull out definite reasons why your posts are getting downvoted. Let me point a few of them out.

First, there's [this answer about a power loss problem on a Opel Meriva with CDTI engine](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/60252/4152). The answer (at this point) has two downvotes on it, with no upvotes. I'd like to point out, two downvotes equate to two different people downvoting your answer. It is doubtful there's a conspiracy on this answer to have two people downvote you. As far as the answer itself, you give an answer which might be of use to a car with a regular gas engine, but within the body of the question, it states it's a CDTI engine, which is clearly diesel operated to anyone who has been around the subject for any length of time. When this was pointed out in the comments, you basically acknowledge you didn't know this (ie: "*ah well in that case*"). If you didn't know enough to answer the question correctly or with some sort of knowledge, I'm not sure why you were answering it at all. I'm sure this is why, on this answer, you garnered the downvotes. There are several comments on the answer. While none of them specify they downvoted you, it could definitely be interpreted that way they might have.

[In this answer about v6 Mustang wear and tear](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/59810/4152), you basically just throw an answer out there which really doesn't give an answer. It tells the OP what they might want to do, but really doesn't explain why it might be the correct answer. Then you state in the comments to just throw it out as an answer and put something else in its place. This, too, is a regular faux pas around here.

In either this or the other case, people who have been around for a while who might make these types of "mistakes" would either edit their answer to better conform with the question or delete their answer altogether.

You state you've been around as a mod on other sites. While this may be true, you still do not seem very knowledgeable about how Stack Exchange works. You say:

> ... this community it seems this place may have thrived years ago but it may have turned into a haunt that caters to the few rather than the many.

I would contend you couldn't be more wrong. While we may not get a huge amount of questions here on MVM&R (I think we were getting ~15/day last time I looked), all you need to do is look at Stack Overflow's question count of nearly 7k questions per day, 10 million visits, and 9.6 million users to know it's far from a haunt.

I propose to you, if you'd take the time to review the [Help Center](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/help) topics a little bit, then spend some time rummaging around the older, more popular questions, you'll get a feel for what gets upvoted as a good answer. Then take a look at some on the other end of the scale to see what gets downvoted. I'm sure it will become plainly clear before long what you might need to do to get better recognition with more reputation and respect for your answers.

Please don't take this as me trying to insult you or be passive aggressive. You asked the question, so I'm trying to answer as honestly as possible with you. Take your time and read the questions before you answer. When you do answer, try to ensure you are directly answering the question with purposeful content and forethought as to what you're trying to say. If you don't know what's going on in a question, ask qualifying questions in the comments. When all is said and done, you'll do just fine.

Comment: Dude thank you, i read everything you said. I'll look into the help center and i'll start reviewing more so I can get a much better feel. I'm very grateful that you responded and someone

Comment: Yeah i just needed some guidance

Comment: @dirtysnowball - We were all new once. If more people would look back on how it was then, they wouldn't be so quick to judge now. No need to thank me, that's what I'm here for ... If you would like, you can always come over to [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), our chat room, and get to know some of the regulars.

Comment: Dude thank you, i read everything you said. I'll look into the help center and i'll start reviewing more so I can get a much better feel. I'm very grateful that you responded and took the time to help me. I want to say sorry I have come off as harsh i think this place is not a haunt at all. I will admit I was pretty wrong on my answers. I will try to be more understanding as i am new, although I've been a lurker. I am sorry for any waves I might be making. I am just a newbie kind of flailing. I think I will do just fine I can't thank you enough I needed guidance baaad. Thank you paulster2